Can I send text messages through a USB-connected cellular modem on Windows?
I almost always utilize GNU/Linux. However, recently I have to utilize Windows for a little while. As such I am having some difficulty finding some functionalities.
On GNU/Linux, you can utilize a variety of tools to send text messages if you have access to a USB LTE Modem / Cellular Dongle (Chatty, ModemManager, and I think even Pidgin). But, alas, I cannot find if similar functionality is available on Windows.
Does Windows support sending/receiving text messages? How can I recieve text messages on my Windows laptop?

Typically a GUI software installed alongside the modem driver, provided by the vendor and/or ISP, handles that. There are also generic software that you can easily google (why didn't you before asking?). That said, software recommendations are off-topic here (on-topic at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Hello @ChanganAuto, >"google (why didn't you before asking?)." no worries. However, I wanted to point out that if you had googled; you would have realized almost all search results refer to unrelated software (linking phone with Windows, VOIP software, ect). Regardless, I appreciate your comment. Have you tested this out for yourself or are you presuming functionality is available?

No, there are a few apps in Micorosft Store and elsewhere for the purpose as asked, not VoIP, not with a phone. This isn't a forum either, comments are for clarification, not for discussion. Your question will likely be closed soon. Feel free to post it where it's on-topic as already mentioned.

Such software definitely used to exist back in the day (before Android), but most of it tended to be manufacturer-specific multi-tools rather than generic SMS-only apps (though the SMS-sending AT commands are generic)... and of course Google is Google and it's getting much harder to find results from 2000s.

Yes, but it's not built-in. You have to download and install an app to achieve this. You can try AirDroid, MightyText, Pushbullet or SMS Bomber, to name a few. Let us know when you're able to successfully send text messages via one of these apps on Windows.

BTW, there are various online tools to send text from a browser, e.g., https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-sites-to-send-free-text-messages-to-cell-phones-sms/ , https://www.alphr.com/free-online-texting-tools/

@Mastaxx The last Huawei 4G modem I used, many years ago, worked by emulating Ethernet over USB and, consequently, was managed from its "webserver" where, among the typical features, it had the ability to view and send SMS/MMS.

Windows does not have a native tool for sending SMS messages, so, no it does not "support" "sending/receiving text messages.
Windows allows software to do pretty much anything it likes, and with the appropriate hardware and drivers you can totally send SMS messages, so, yes, it does "support" sending/receiving text messages.
